# Invalid Dimensions trying to save chart as image (Office2010 related)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save charts in excel-vba as images. For this I am using the code below. This works great with Excel 2007 but Excel 2010 needs a greater dimensions for the chart object that needs to be greated. So I use the + 4 instead of + 1. Doing this I have a line at the bottom and the right side (looks like a frame). Has someone an idea on how to get rid of these lines?

```
        '1. copy to clipboard
        '2. create new chart object with greater dimensions (office 2010 requirement), round because shape size is double (e.g. 200.5px)
        '3. Paste clipboard content
        '4. export chart, delete afterwards
        Dim shp As Shape
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Set sht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)
        Set shp = sht.Shapes(chrtName)
        shp.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        Dim objChart As ChartObject
        Set objChart = sht.ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, Round(shp.Width + 1, 0), Round(shp.Height + 1, 0))

        'Set objChart = sht.ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, Round(shp.Width + 4, 0), Round(shp.Height + 4, 0))

        objChart.Activate
        ActiveChart.Paste
        ActiveChart.Export Filename:=fullPath, Filtername:=Right(fullPath, 3)
        objChart.Delete
```